# How to get Storefrontcontext in XC 10.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-search

Using SC10.1 & XC 10.1
I'm trying to get catalog items with a search criteria.
The code in this [Sitecore document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/commerce-search-results-mvc-view.html) to get the Storefrontcontext is not working.
[image]

```
var searchManager = CommerceTypeLoader.CreateInstance<ISearchManager>();
var storefrontContext = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IStorefrontContext>();
SearchRepository searchRepository = new SearchRepository(searchManager, storefrontContext);
searchRepository.SearchCatalogItemsByKeyword("mdn","Brand", 10);
```

> 'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetRequestService' and no accessible extension method
> 'GetRequestService' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceProvider' could be found.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**
You can create a constructor and then find it from there as follows -

```
public IStorefrontContext StorefrontContext { get; set; }

public ISearchManager SearchManager { get; set; }

public YourController(IStorefrontContext storefrontContext, ISearchManager searchManager)
{
    this.StorefrontContext = storefrontContext;    
    this.SearchManager = searchManager;   
}
```

Then you can use your above code as -

```
SearchRepository searchRepository = new SearchRepository(this.SearchManager, this.StorefrontContext);
searchRepository.SearchCatalogItemsByKeyword("mdn","Brand", 10);
```

**Solution 2 :**
If you want to use your code as is then add reference of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` in your solution and use
`using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` in your class

**EDIT :** If you haven't added your controller in config then need to add it as below. Create a patch file and add below lines -

```
<services>
      <register
        serviceType="abc.Feature.Catalog.Controllers.YourController, abc.Feature.Catalog"
        implementationType="abc.Feature.Catalog.Controllers.YourController, abc.Feature.Catalog"
        lifetime="Transient" />
</services>
```

Comment: I tried both solutions. It is null in both cases. Even tried including `Sitecore.DependencyInjection` namespace with no luck.

Comment: The first soln. worked after adding the patch config.